# Problem installing Event::Lib with libevent on Mac OSX

Tags: perl, libevent

I am trying to perform a cpan install of Event::Lib on a Mac OSX 10.15.4. When I first tried to run cpan I found it needed the libevent library. I downloaded, built, and installed that. Now I am getting a number of errors with ev_arg not being defined:

> Lib.xs:692:33: error: no member named 'ev_arg' in 'struct event'
>               SvREFCNT_dec((SV*)args->ev.ev_arg);
>                                 ~~~~~~~~ ^

ev_arg is defined in one of the internal header files which are not installed. There isn't an error for a missing header so moving that header won't help. What should I do to get this module to install?
thanks

Comment: According to the Event::Lib's [source](https://metacpan.org/source/VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03/Lib.xs#L12), it uses `event.h` but according to `libevent`s [GitHub page](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/include/event.h#L34), *"The <event.h> header is deprecated in Libevent 2.0 and later; please use <event2/event.h> instead"* Apparently the module is quite old and has not been upgraded to libevent version 2

Comment: There seems to be some GitHub repos that has upgraded to version 2, see [vovkasm/perl-libevent](https://github.com/vovkasm/perl-libevent), and [sbertrang/perl-libevent](https://github.com/sbertrang/perl-libevent)

Comment: Maybe you could try the [EV](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MLEHMANN/EV-4.33/EV.pm) module instead?

Comment: [Last change](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Event-Lib)  was in ... 2007?  Pick another module. There are many for event-driven work

Comment: Then there's [this blog](http://blogs.perl.org/users/vladimir_lettiev/2014/09/eventlib.html), from Sep 2014 as well (as Hakon's links) ... I wonder whatever happened with these, if anything.  But there are surely other options anyway

Comment: @zdim There was [an upload](https://metacpan.org/release/CRUX/Event-Lib-1.04) of version 1.04 in 2014, but it seems to have been marked as unauthorized. Apparently, it contains [many changes](https://metacpan.org/source/CRUX/Event-Lib-1.04) but unfortunately none is registered in the `Changes` file

Comment: @HåkonHægland Ah, interesting.  I guess there just wasn't enough interest for that to be fully revived.